# seconds passed since i closed an app in swift/xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, time

I need a  simple  method of counting the seconds between the last time i closed an app and i opened it....is there any simple way to do so?

Nothing else in the code needs changing, only number of seconds between "lastAppClosingTime' and "app Launched is needed.
I am thinking about using the 'timeserving' but I', unsure if it'll be efficient

I have a countdown in my app, requiring the user to  press a button 10 minutes before the end, however i have no idea how to make the app calculate whenever the user failed the LAST check or not

Answer (score 2):

You can store time when you app is to be terminated, one once the app is launched compare the last close date with current time, as such (goes to AppDelegate.swift):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "TerminatedAt") as? Date {
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: date, to: Date())
        let numberOfSecondsSinceAppClosed = components.second ?? 0
    }

    return true
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "TerminatedAt")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```